# merging multiple system variables in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, path

Windows 10 system variables are typically path references.  Is it possible to add multiple path references to a single variable?  I have a lot of variables related to JAVA or ANDROIDSTUDIO and other packages, thus creating a single combined/merged variable would greatly reduce the amount of variables I need to create and what needs to be added to the main system `PATH` variable.

Using java as an example, normally, we see:

```
JAVA_HOME = "C:\path\to\java\jdk1.8.0_301"
JAVA_JRE = "%JAVA_HOME%\jre"
JAVA_BIN = "%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
JAVA_LIB = "%JAVA_HOME%\lib" 
PATH = "%JAVA_JRE%;%JAVA_JDK%,%JAVA_LIB%" (3 variables added to PATH)
```

But could the following be done instead, still define the individual variables (maybe needed by specific apps), and then create a single XXX_PATH to be added to main `PATH`:

```
JAVA_HOME = "C:\path\to\java\jdk1.8.0_301"
JAVA_JRE = "%JAVA_HOME%\jre"
JAVA_BIN = "%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
JAVA_LIB = "%JAVA_HOME%\lib" 
JAVA_PATHS = "%JAVA_JRE%;%JAVA_JDK%,%JAVA_LIB%"
PATH = ""%Other_Vars%;%Other_Paths%;%JAVA_PATHS%"
```

Or even simpler:

```
JAVA_HOME = "C:\path\to\java\jdk1.8.0_301"
JAVA_PATHS = "%JAVA_HOME%\jre;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\lib" 
PATH = "%Other_Vars%;%Other_Paths%;%JAVA_PATHS%"
```

Doing something like this will greatly help me keep my variables organized and reduce the number of variables I am always adding to `PATH`.

If this can be done, are there any issues I need to be aware of?

Comment: Just keep in mind that system variable have a maximum length.  So creating a single system variable that contains everything has it's own problems. Have you tried what you are suggesting?

Comment: Always good to try it out and post results, but I doubt this will work. I think I've seen programs that use the environment variable to concatenate with a command (e.g. `${PROGRAM_HOME}\some_bin.exe`, but what happens if `PROGRAM_HOME` is not one path, but a series of paths? The resulting full path then becomes meaningless.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke - Good point.  I suppose I could still create the individual system XXX variables, add them all to a single XXX_PATH, and then add the XXX_PATH variable to the main system `PATH`

Comment: What's the point in that? I don't think I follow... However, I think it's maybe better to focus on the actual issue you're having. What problem are your trying to solve? Is it setting a bunch of variables? A script should be able to do that. Feel free to edit your question to make it more about the issue, instead of the solution you have in mind.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke - i updated OP with two option scenarios, where the first takes into account your previous point about programs needing specific environment variables but also reduces the PATH variable and the second minimizes both the total amount of variables and Path variables

Comment: You're still very much focussing on an intended solution, instead of the actual problem you're trying to solve. This can lead to an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/222653). Besides, you don't show any research effort in your question (only proposed solutions). This other question might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/834944/1256347